# background image repeat error in resize

Tags: html, css

I set an image as a background for my website. I used the following style for it.

```
#whole_wrapper{ background-image:url(../images/wrapper_bg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100%; float:left; height:116px}
```

It display correctly in normal screen resolution. If i resize the screen it doesn't repeat correctly.How can i correct it.

Comment: What is "resize the screen"? You mean the browser window, or do you change the hardware settings of the monitor while the browser is running? In any case, do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Other question. Why do you have both `width:100%` and `float:left`? Those seem to counteract each other. And "doesn't repeat correctly" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
width: 100%; on body
and
min-width: 1024px; width: 100%; on whole_wrapper

It should works.

The problem is you've assigned the width as 100%, so when you resize the width of the screen is more than 100%, do you understand?